# Playing sound in Java 7

Tags: java, fedora, javasound

I am trying to play a sound file in Java. I have written this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class SoundBang
{
    private File _file;
    private AudioInputStream _audio;
    private Clip _clip;

    public SoundBang( )
    {
        _file = new File( "file/sound/bang.wav" );

        try
        {
            _audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( _file );
            _clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
            _clip.open( _audio );
            _clip.start( );
        }
        catch ( LineUnavailableException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedAudioFileException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[ ] args )
    {
        new SoundBang( );
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not hear anything when I run this code.

The URL of the sound file is correct (I tested it by printing the Absolute URL and it is fine). I'm using Eclipse Juno, openjdk-7 and Fedora 17 with KDE.

Comment: Have you tried not setting the MicroSecondPosition after starting?

Comment: Well, I think this sentence isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things:

1. clip.start spawns a new thread to execute in the background and it dies when the app dies. Try sleeping after starting the clip.
2. Is it necessary to seek forward after you start? It seems like that's just an extra line.

Try making your main method:

```
public static void main ( String[ ] args )
{
    new SoundBang( );
    Thread.sleep(2000); // Sleep 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I just located the Thread.sleep(2000) above _clip.start() to adjust the class to my needs. Thank you!

Comment: @BrallanAguilar Of course sleeping is just a simplistic way to make it work right, and isn't necessarily the best answer. You may want to use a "half-busy" wait by using a while loop in combination with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#isRunning() isRunning() and sleeping for a half second every iteration, that'll allow you to wait for any length clip to complete.